# Nginx rewrite issue with sub folder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm try to redirect an URL but nothings happen. :(
The source URL example like this:

```
http://example.com/download.php?shortURL=MJdcqV
```

Where the `MJdcqV` is a variable parameter, all others constant.
I need to redirect looks like this:

```
http://example.com/views/download.php?shortURL=MJdcqV
```

I'm try to rewrite with many way, but not find the right way:

```
location /download.php {
        rewrite ^/download.php$ /views/download.php redirect;
        rewrite ^/download.php$ /views/download.php break;
        rewrite ^/download.php$ /views/download.php last;
}
```

Please gime me some advice or pointing me for the right way.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want the user's browser to get a redirect, that is, see the redirected URL, or do you want the redirect happen only at server end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
location = /download.php {
  rewrite ^ /views/download.php$is_args$args last;
}
```